# Can I just create and store list of auth tokens instead of using JWT and similar?

Tags: database, rest, authentication, jwt

I'm creating my first SPA using NodeJS stack for development and I came to a point where I should design authentication and secure some parts of the app.
I read a lot about auth techniques including JWT, OAuth, etc. but I still didn't find something like «a real world example».
Let's assume that my task is just to secure some parts of app from public. My app isn't designed to work with 3rd party services so I see no need to use something like Google or Facebook auth. I want to use login/password and store all this data using my own database server.
I don't understand the point of having authentication stateless. I came to a simple conclusion that I can design authentication in this way:

- I store users logins and passwords in my database.
- User auth means that user enters his credentials, server checks it and creates token. Then server saves this token into database. User saves token using browser local storage or somewhere else if it's not browser environment.
- On each request client sends this token, server checks that this token exists and responds appropriately.
- User can login from different devices, we just create multiple tokens for him.
- We can end specific session or all sessions by just deleting user tokens from database.
- We can manage tokens in a way we want, for example server can check expiration time and invalidate (delete) token.

Is it OK? JWT require additional implementation if we need to invalidate token, I saw different examples, all of them were based on storing *invalid* tokens but what's the point of that if we can just store *valid* tokens? We already lose statelessness by implementing this storage.
I see that I can just use cookies instead of implementation described above but I don't like an idea to use cookies in RESTful app because it really depends on browser-like client environment.
What are the disadvantages of just storing tokens on server?

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented one project in which user authentication is required and token is stored into database.

You can find that example [here](https://github.com/sohamdodia/products-node-api).

Answer (score 0):

You are describing the traditional authentication approach using session cookies. The server stores a session for each connected user identified by a `sessionid`. The `sessionid` is stored by client in a cookie and sent in each following request to identify user.

You can use this method perfectly, both in browsers or mobile devices (using the device storage instead of a cookie)

The drawback is that it **requires many server resources to keep sessions open and requires database queries at each authentication to retrieve user data. This is what JWT solves.** The user information goes in the token itself, and is reliable because it is signed with the secret key of the server.

JWT has its own drawbacks, for example it is not useful if you need to have a revocation list, because them will require server storage.